# Cordova build for windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Our application has to support windows phone 8, windows phone 8.1 and windows phone 10 and has to be hosted in windows store. Need help to understand the number of builds need to create.

1. Can we have single build for all three versions (Will the single appx file works for all the version)?
2. Or Do we need to have one build (.xap file) for windows phone 8 and another build (.appx file) for 8.1 and 10?

Answer (score 0):

On windows phone 10 silverlight version of apps will not work only win-RT app will run windows 10 devices, and windows phone 8 has only Silverlight version (.xap)

You have to have multiple builds to support windows phone 8. i.e option 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp8`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/wp8/index.html) platform for Windows Phone 8.0 (xap) and [`windows`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html) platform for Windows 8.0/Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10/Windows 10 Mobile (appx).